# I have deployed my WordPress site (osmfancytext.com) on Netlify - sitemap_index.xml is empty

Tags: wordpress, netlify, xml-sitemap, static-pages

I have live my WP site on Netlify static pages but my Yoast plugin (sitemap_index.xml) showing empty why?

site URL: [https://osmfancytext.com/](https://osmfancytext.com)

I have expect to show my all site pages, post media inside the

https://osmfancytext.com/sitemap_index.xml

Comment: SEO plugins generate site maps. Which one do you use? Dos it support your static-site configuration? Please [edit] your question to tell us more,